# How to translate the Opportunity Split object?

Tags: translation, translation-workbench

Is there any way to translate the Opportunity Split object and its standard fields?

The object is not accessible from the "Rename Tabs and Labels" Setup section for both standard objects:

[image]

And custom ones:

[image]

I thought that maybe there would be Opportunity Split fields possible to translate inside the Opportunity translations, but sadly it wasn't the case.

Has anyone tried to translate this object before?

**Edit:**

Ok, so I created a metadata file for Opp Split translation manually, similarly to other ones that I had already had and called it `OpportunitySplit-da.objectTranslation-meta.xml`.

I filled it with the following markup and succeeded to deploy to my Org:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObjectTranslation xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <caseValues>
        <article>Definite</article>
        <plural>false</plural>
        <value>Splitty</value>
    </caseValues>
    <caseValues>
        <article>Indefinite</article>
        <plural>false</plural>
        <value>Splitty</value>
    </caseValues>
    <caseValues>
        <article>None</article>
        <plural>false</plural>
        <value>Splitty</value>
    </caseValues>
    <caseValues>
        <article>Definite</article>
        <plural>true</plural>
        <value>Splitty</value>
    </caseValues>
    <caseValues>
        <article>Indefinite</article>
        <plural>true</plural>
        <value>Splitty</value>
    </caseValues>
    <caseValues>
        <article>None</article>
        <plural>true</plural>
        <value>Splitty</value>
    </caseValues>
    <gender>Feminine</gender>
</CustomObjectTranslation>
```

Looks like it worked, but partially. The "Opportunity Split" component got its translation changed:

[image]

But in the screen for modifying Splits there are two tabs that still need their translation - Revenue and Overlay:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how could I set the translation for these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked SF support about that. Looks like it's currently not possible to translate the Opportunity Split object fields, here's their answer:

> Most standard tabs and objects can be renamed but not all. For example, the Forecasts tab is not available for renaming **so as the case with Opportunity Split**.
>
> Please find below article for reference: [Considerations for Renaming Tab and Field Labels](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_rename_considerations.htm&type=5)